# Error import tornado in python 3

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3

I'm using raspberry pi 3 to communicate with an android app through websocket. I installed tornado on my raspberry and the installation was succesfull but if I use it with python 2.7 I haven't any kind of problem but I need to use it with python 3 and when I just write "import tornado" I get an ImportError: No module named "tornado". It is like if it is installed in python 2 but not in 3. Both python 2 and 3 are preinstalled on raspberry. Somebody can help me? Thanks in advance
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: How did you install tornado?

Comment: pip install tornado

Comment: use pip3 install tornado maybe

Comment: I tried, but I get an error:
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pk80pa7z/tornado/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d_dlctwz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pk80pa7z/tornado

Answer (score 0):

In these days the website of tornado has some problem. I downloaded the tar.gz file from another website and installed from there. Instead of use command "python" use "python3"